# Stop stan when it reaches convergence (Rhat = 1)

Tags: r, bayesian, convergence, hierarchical-bayesian, stan

I'm doing a Bayesian analysis, which involves changing the warmup and iterations (many times per day). I wanted to know if there is a loop to automatically change warmups and interactions and stop the model when it reaches convergence (Rhat = 1)?

If it exists?
Where can I get information on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a programming question, which will probably be closed as off-topic. You might try on stackoverflow, where it might be on-topic, or the stan community has it's own forums here: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/

Comment: @RobertLong, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\hat R$ doesn’t mean that your model converged. Is is one of several criteria that can be used to judge convergence. Usually you should not any of the criteria alone, but look at several different criteria. As noticed by Aki Vehtari et al (2019), there are cases where it fails. Moreover, when MCMC sampling you’re not only concerned about convergence but also about having enough samples to be able to draw conclusions from the data. Using $\hat R$ alone is not the best idea.

Aki Vehtari, Andrew Gelman, Daniel Simpson, Bob Carpenter, and Paul-Christian Bürkner (2019). [Rank-normalization, folding, and localization: An improved R-hat for assessing convergence of MCMC.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08008) arXiv preprint arXiv:1903.08008